# Edit cell of Google Spreadhseet via API

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-sheets-api

I am building a Chrome extension which should edit a cell in a Google Spreadsheet. I manage to read the sheet content but am not able to edit a cell. Currently my error is "400 (Bad Request)". Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

I have gone through the Google Sheets API documentation and other posted questions here but was not able to find any solution.

Here is the code which I use to GET the sheet content (this works):

```
function loadSpreadsheet(token) {

    var y = new XMLHttpRequest();
    y.open('GET', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1NE8g7kyk-Z6Sci9_w6mdY2KV8542a3TJd9lIbucHZiU/default/private/values?access_token=' + token);
    y.onload = function() {
        console.log(y.response);
    };
    y.send();

}
```

And this is the code I try to edit (PUT) a new cell (gives me "400 - Bad Request"):

```
function add_title(message, token) {

    url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1NE8g7kyk-Z6Sci9_w6mdY2KV8542a3TJd9lIbucHZiU/default/private/full/cell?access_token=' + token;

    function constructAtomXML(foo){
        var atom = ["<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>",
            '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">',
            '<id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1NE8g7kyk-Z6Sci9_w6mdY2KV8542a3TJd9lIbucHZiU/default/private/full/R2C4</id>',
            '<link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1NE8g7kyk-Z6Sci9_w6mdY2KV8542a3TJd9lIbucHZiU/default/private/full/R2C4"/>',
            '<gs:cell row="2" col="4" inputValue="',foo,'"/>',
            '</entry>'].join('');
        return atom;
    };

    var params = constructAtomXML(message);

    var z = new XMLHttpRequest();
    z.open("PUT", url);
    z.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/atom+xml");
    z.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");
    z.send(params);

}
```

Comment: "params" object should be a String. You just need to pass a value you want to send to the server. Did you check the type of message parameter in "var params = constructAtomXML(message);" Also check this line should be '<gs:cell row="2" col="4" inputValue ="foo">' ,foo,'</gs:cell>',

Comment: @gui47 I checked "params" and it returns a string. I also removed the variable part of the line to make it '<gs:cell row="2" col="4" inputValue="foo">' but  that does also not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: [Update values in google spreadsheets from nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105535/unable-to-update-values-in-google-spreadsheets-from-nodejs-using-the-cell-based) - Looks like they put the OAuth key in the header.

Comment: @eddyparkinson I tried to add the token through 'z.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin Auth=" + token)' but I am still getting the 400 error.

Comment: @theGreatDanton any idea what is wong? I assume the code you posted in the linked question works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comments I finally got it: I had to add *OAuth* and *If-Match* to the header of the request.

The final codes should look like this:

```
function add_title(token, message) {

    url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1NE8g7kyk-Z6Sci9_w6mdY2KV8542a3TJd9lIbucHZiU/default/private/basic/R2C4?access_token=' + token;

    function constructAtomXML(foo){
        var atom = ["<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>",
            '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">',
            '<id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/key/private/basic/R2C4</id>',
            '<link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/key/default/private/basic/R2C4"/>',
            '<gs:cell row="2" col="4" inputValue="' + foo + '"/>',
            '</entry>'].join('');
        return atom;
    };

    var params = constructAtomXML(message);

    var z = new XMLHttpRequest();
    z.open("PUT", url);
    z.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/atom+xml");
    z.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");
    z.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);
    z.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
    z.send(params);

}
```